# Faster way (keyboard shortcuts?) to use quick fixes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I often use the Eclipse feature (Galileo) of suggested error corrections to automatically create code stubs or to refactor things. For example, I would write a method that calls other methods which don't exist yet, then move the mouse over the error message and click on "create method". Or, change `this` to the class name and choose "add `static` modifier" from the quick fixes.

I think this is very convenient because it lets me stay in one place in my code and sort of "remotely" wire up what's not currently visible on my screen. What I think is annoying though, is that I have to leave the keyboard, hover my mouse over the error symbol, wait for the tooltip to pop up, and click on the option (doing that, I sometimes move the mouse a little over the edge and the tooltip goes away again - very annoying).

Am I missing a faster method here? I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut, but then I have overlooked stuff from the huge preference dialog before.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> : Quick Fix.
(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> on Mac)

Just put your cursor on the part you suspect you can perform an action (correction, refactoring, ...) and hit the `Quick Fix` shortcut. The same popup will be displayed, and you can select the right option with the up and down keys.

[image: Europa spell]

That, combined with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (`Quick Access`) gives you most of eclipse features at your fingertips ;)

See also:

- [Eclipse Tip: Shortcut to Quick Fix](http://www.vasanth.in/2006/08/31/eclipse-tip-shortcut-to-quick-fix/)
- [My Favorite Eclipse Shortcut: Quick Fix](http://depth-first.com/articles/2008/01/11/my-favorite-eclipse-shortcut-quick-fix)
- [**Eclipse hotkeys**](http://www.pleso.net/en/publications/2008/03/24/eclipse-hotkeys/): eclipse shortcuts gold mine.

Comment: Yay! Thanks, didn't see that.

Comment: That's Cmd-1 on Mac, in case that helps anyone.

Comment: @SilverSideDown good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: In a highly annoying way, eclipse requires to type Ctrl+Shift+1 on some/most keyboards :-(

Answer (score 1):

As an additional tip, a specific type of quick fix I use all the time has a dedicated shortcut:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>: Add Javadoc comment stub for current method.

Answer (score 1):

After using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> like mentioned in the top answer, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to apply the selected fix all to problems of the same category.

Comment: Also, I think the "1" key that has to be pressed is the one of the numeric keypad... Pressing Ctrl + Maj + 1 (where "1" is NOT the "1" of the numeric keypad) doesn't work for me.

Comment: ... Which is not very practical to me because I do not num-lock my numeric keypad...

Comment: and on my eclipse oxygen it isn't working at all, ctrl+1 is working but not the rest

Answer (score 0):

In general, keyboard shortcuts in IDEs (and code tools in general) are coming from a user principle that holds that the more your hands/fingers can remain poised over the keyboard (as in the f-j centered "touch typist" position), the more productive you can become. This is probably why the use of the number keypad is not encouraged, or other keys, less common to the most basic layout keyboard, are not used. Many hold that useful keyboard shortcuts should be easily reachable from this position.

One thing I will say about eclipse keyboard shortcuts is that if you use a popular Windows presentation utility called Zoom-it, you need to turn that off when using eclipse. There are several show-stopper conflicts between the two, such as Ctrl-1 and Ctrl-3.